# File System Encryption and FIPS

Tags: centos, filesystems, encryption, redhat-enterprise-linux

For a while, I am searching for FIPS 140-2 certification and OS level encryption for Red Hat and Centos. I am not very sure about the answers regarding to this certification. My question is does Red Hat provide a solution certified by FIPS 140-2 for file system encryption? LUKS (for Centos) seems not certified but I also want to know if there is a certified solution in Red Hat for this?or for Centos?

Comment: If you require this certification, surely you can ask Red Hat directly?

Comment: Did you see this : https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/Certificate/2657